# Assigning null to an object in the linked list gives error

Tags: java, sorting, doubly-linked-list

I get a `NullPointerException` when I execute this line:

```
temp.previous.next = null;
```

in the last `else` of the code below.

The `Contact` class is a Node of a linked List.

Can anyone see what the problem might be?

```
public Contact delete(){
    Scanner keyboard  =new Scanner(System.in);
    Contact temp = first;
    System.out.print("Enter a name: ");
    String name = keyboard.next();
    while (temp != null) {
        if (temp.name.equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
            break;
        }
        temp = temp.next;
    }
    if (temp == null) {
        System.out.println("record not found.");
    } else if (count == 1) {
        first = null;
        last = null;
        count--;
        return temp;
    } else if (count==2) {
        if (temp == first) {
            temp.next.previous = null;
            first = temp;
            count--;
            return temp;
        } else {
            first.next = null;
            count--;
            return temp;
        }
    } else if (count >= 3) {
        if (temp == first) {
            temp.next.previous = null;
            first = temp.next;
            count--;
            return temp;
        } else {
            if (temp.next != null) {
                temp.next.previous =temp.previous;
                temp.previous.next = temp.next;
                count--;
                return temp;
            } else {
                temp.previous.next = null; // <-- NPE here!
                count--;
                return temp;
            }
        }
    }
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: You ask us to resolve the error, but don't say which error.

Comment: the error is that the following line is not executing (it is located in the last most else of the code): temp.previous.next=null                                                    why is this so? and what will be the correction?

Comment: how you mean not executing? could you give some more details? or a stacktrace with the exception? and can you tell what is the prefered outcome?

Comment: @sot question any better now?

Comment: @Bohemian Yeah, good edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are assigning `null` to `temp.previous.next`, but nowhere do you check that `temp.previous` is not null.

Further, you initialize `temp` with  `first`, which presumably (being "first") has no previous node - ie `temp.previous` would probably be null.

Thus it is likely you are getting a `NullPointerException` attempting to execute the problem code.

QED.